# hide the div on scrolling and show it when cursor reaches to a certain distance from the top

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Description :**

I have a div with `width: 100%` of the body and is sicked to the top of the page.

Now when I start scrolling I want the `div` to hide itself when it is no longer the part of visible page after scrolling e.g `slideUp` "But" when I start to take my cursor near the top of my page the `div` should re-appear when the cursor is at certain distance from the top of the page

Now I could use the following demo code

```
$(document).on("scrollstart",function(){
  alert("Started scrolling!");
});
```

but then

1) I dont how to detect if the div is out of the visible page after scrolling

2) and how to detect the y-distance of the cursor from the top of the page...

any one??

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea:
1. Try getting offset of scroll top and compare it with the height of div that you want to hide (if div height is less than scroll top, hide it)
2. Maybe you can get cursor position using something like this: http://api.jquery.com/event.pagex/